# Prove that Baire space $\omega^\omega$ is completely metrizable?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, the-baire-space

When I tried to prove that Baire space $\omega^\omega$ is completely metrizable, I defined a metric $d$ on $\omega^\omega$ as: If $g,h \in \omega^\omega$ then let $d(g,h)=1/(n+1)$ where $n$ is the smallest element in $\omega$ so that $g(n) \ne h(n)$ is such $n$ exists, and $d(g,h)=0$ otherwise.

I am stuck trying to prove this metric is complete. Can you help me please? 
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 8):

The point here is that two functions are close iff they agree on an initial segment, that is, $d(f,g)\le 1/(n+1)$ iff $f(0)=g(0),f(1)=g(1),\dots,f(n-1)=g(n-1)$. Now, if $(f_n)_n$ is a Cauchy sequence, then, for each $n$, there is $N_n$ such that for all $m,k>N_n$ we have $d(f_m,f_k)\le1/(n+1)$. That is, all functions $f_m$ with $m>N_n$ agree on their first $n$ values.

This suggests naturally what the limit of the sequence $(f_n)_n$ should be: Define $f:\omega\to\omega$ simply by setting $f(k)$ to be the common value $f_m(k)$ for all $m$ large enough (say, for all $m>N_{k+1}$). To verify that $f$ is indeed the limit of the $f_n$, note that, by construction, for any $k$, $d(f_m,f)<1/(k+1)$ as long as $m>N_{k+1}$. But this is precisely what $\lim_m f_m=f$ means.

One of the many things that make $\omega^\omega$ with this metric interesting is that, as a topological space, this is just the irrationals. (Of course, the metric is not the Euclidean metric restricted to the irrationals, since the irrationals are clearly not a complete metric space under the standard metric.) A nice proof of this is at the very beginning of Arnie Miller's [monograph](https://projecteuclid.org/ebooks/lecture-notes-in-logic/Descriptive-Set-Theory-and-Forcing--How-to-Prove-Theorems/toc/lnl/1235423343) on descriptive set theory and forcing.

Answer (score 2):

Let $x_n$ be a Cauchy sequence.  Then $d(x_n, x_{n+1}) \rightarrow 0$.  In particular, for every $\epsilon > 0$, there exists an $N$ such that $n > N$ implies $d(x_n, x_{n+1}) < \epsilon$.

Exercise:  translate that statement into one relating $\omega^n$ and $\omega^{n+1}$ (or equivalently, prefixes in finite trees).

Exercise:  what happens when $n \rightarrow \omega$?

A different metric might make this easier.  In fact, I'd say that the only thing keeping this problem from being "trivial" is picking a metric that makes the argument trivial.

Comment: I fear your mention of trees and prefixes may end up obscuring the idea for the OP.

Comment: You might be right.  I think prefixes/initial segments are pretty natural.  I considered countable choice, too, but it might be too magical for the context.

Comment: Hopefully the OP will find them natural *eventually*.

Comment: Agreed.  I was trying to lead him to the aha of it. :)