# Are second-countable metric spaces $\sigma$-compact?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

I was curious about the relations between second-countable, separable, Lindelöf and $\sigma$-compact topologies in the context of metric spaces.

I am aware of the following implications in general topological spaces:

- second-countable $\Rightarrow$ separable $\not \Rightarrow$ Lindelöf, $\;$ [thanks [bof](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/111012/bof)]
- $\sigma$-compact $\Rightarrow$ Lindelöf
- second-countable + locally compact $\Rightarrow$ $\sigma$-compact

as well as the reversed implications in the case of metric spaces:

- Lindelöf $\Leftrightarrow$ separable $\Leftrightarrow$ second-countable

Since all the proofs I've seen so far require the LC condition I assume it is not true in general that second-countable topological spaces are $\sigma$-compact (although seeing an actual counterexample would be nice). 
 So what about metrizable topological spaces?

**Ideas so far:** 
If we can proof that every subset of a $\sigma$-compact space is again $\sigma$-compact, then this would follow from the fact, that every separable metric space is homeomorphic to a subset of the Hilbert cube (which is compact). $\;$[debunked by [bof](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/111012/bof)]

Comment: The set of irrational numbers is a separable metric space which is not $\sigma$-compact. (Every $\sigma$-compact subset of the irrational numbers is meager.) Hilbert space is another example.

Comment: By the way, separable does **not** imply Lindelöf in general topological spaces. For example, the Sorgenfrey plane is separable but not Lindelöf.

Comment: Every closed subset of a $\sigma$-compact space is again $\sigma$-compact. Not all subspace, as witnessed by the rational and the irrationals assubspaces of the reals.

Comment: @bof I also wanted to disprove local compactness.

Comment: Any infinite-dimensional separable Banach space is a counterexample. This follows from the fact that the unit ball of a Banach space $E$ is compact iff $E$ is finite dimensional, so a compact subset of an infinite dimensional Banach space has empty interior. Then we just apply the Baire category theorem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A counterexample is the "[Baire space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baire_space_(set_theory))" $\mathcal{N} = \mathbb{N}^{\mathbb{N}}$.  This is one of the main examples of a Polish space: a separable, completely metrizable space.

One fact about this space is that all compact subsets have empty interior, that is, all compact subsets are nowhere dense.  By the [Baire Category Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baire_category_theorem), $\mathcal{N}$ is not the countable union of nowhere dense subsets, and so together with the above fact it cannot be $\sigma$-compact.

See also this question and its answer for more details:

- [Is the Baire space $\sigma$-compact?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/709742/614523)