# Is a polish space sigma compact?

Tags: general-topology, polish-spaces

Is a polish space (complet metric separable topological space) sigma compact ?

Thanks and regards.

Answer (score 3):

Not in general - indeed baire space $\omega^\omega$ is not $\sigma$-compact. cf. [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/709751/655547).

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: the irrationals as a subspace of the real line are not $F_\sigma$ (the rationals are not $G_\delta$), so the irrationals are not $\sigma$-compact.

Answer (score 3):

Another example, [Hilbert space](https://topology.pi-base.org/spaces/S000030) $l^2$.  Complete separable metric, but not sigma compact.

Comment: I thought so too at first, but it actually is $\sigma$-compact. Just start with the 1-ball in one dimension and then - step by step - increase dimension and radius.

Comment: Wrong.  Think about it.  The vector $(1,1/2,1/3,1/4,\cdots)$ is not in your union.  Hilbert space is not equal to $$\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty \mathbb R^n$$

Comment: You're right. I was wrong. But good that we talked about it. ;-)

Comment: @amsmath in an infinite dimensional TVS a compact subset has empty interior, and a $\sigma$-compact TVS  is thus meagre (e.g. all eventually $0$ sequences in the sup norm is an example of it) so cannot be Polish.

Comment: Thank you, why $\mathcal{l}^{2}$ is not sigma compact ?

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Is there an easy proof for normed spaces? Is it possibly true that a compact set is always contained in a finite-dimensional subspace?

Comment: @amsmath ... **Is it possibly true that a compact set is always contained in a finite-dimensional subspace?** no.  For example, a convergent sequence, together with its limit, is a compact set.  Perhaps you can find an example like that in Hilbert space not contained in any finite-dimensional subspace.   WARNING ... new questions should not be posted as comments.

Comment: @CechMS because it’s Polish it cannot be $\sigma$-compact.

Comment: why ? What is the proof ?